# Observablevalue check for new and old values equally

Tags: javafx, observable

In fact I have a class that performs the job of collecting website post URL.The url article I get when analyzing each page site

```
+http://dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi.htm
+http://dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi/trang-2.htm
....
+http://dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi/trang-9998.htm
+http://dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi/trang-n.htm
```

to the Property url is as follows.

```
 public class Pagination {

    private final StringProperty postURL = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public String getPostURL() {
        return postURL.get();
    }

    public void setPostURL(String value) {
        postURL.set(value);
    }

    public StringProperty postURLProperty() {
        return postURL;
    }

    public void gather() {
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        for (String url : getAllURLToPage("http://dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi/trang-"+i+".htm")) {
            setPostURL(url);
        }
     }
    }
}
```

From page `http://dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi/trang-9998.htm===->http://dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi/trang-n.htm`.

The post url value is constant, so I want to terminate the program when consecutive url are equal,eg newValue.equals(oldValue) as below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pagination pagination = new Pagination();
        pagination.postURLProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                if (newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
                    System.out.println("BREAK");
                }
            }
        });
        pagination.gather();
    }
```

That's just the example by newValue and oldValue are always not equal with observableValue.

I hope you help me solve my problem how can i control post url i get

Comment: A change listener only gets invoked when the value changes. So if you call `urlProperty().set(...)` and pass in something equal to the current value, the property doesn't change, and the change listener is not called.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "my statement will stop"? Do you want the `for` loop to exit if the current value is the same as the existing value in the property?

Comment: I will revise the question to make it easier to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in the comment, a `ChangeListener` is invoked in response to a *change* in a property. If you call `postURL.set(...)` and pass the same value that is currently held in `postURL`, the change listener will not be invoked. (TBH it's not really clear what the purpose of the property is here.)

You could just do this in the `for` loop directly:

```
public void gather() {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    for (String url : getAllURLToPage("http://dantri.com.vn/xa-hoi/trang-"+i+".htm")) {
        if (Objects.equals(url, getPostURL())) {
            System.out.println("BREAK");
        }
        setPostURL(url);
    }
 }
}
```

or perhaps in the `set` method, assuming you don't call `postURL.set(...)` anywhere else:

```
public void setPostURL(String value) {
    if (Objects.equals(value, postURL.get())) {
        System.out.println("BREAK");
    }
    postURL.set(value);
}
```

But there is no way for a `ChangeListener` to detect a lack of a change.